# AttributeError: module 'googleads.util' has no attribute 'GetSudsClientFilter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on migration from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8.
I am getting the below error for one program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\\\<path>\googleads\Sales.py", line 66, in <module>
    logging.getLogger('suds.client').addFilter(googleads.util.GetSudsClientFilter())
AttributeError: module 'googleads.util' has no attribute 'GetSudsClientFilter'
```

These are the packages importing in Python 2.7.13.

```
import googleads.errors
import googleads.oauth2
import googleads.util
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using `python 2` with the latest version of the package, from the projects developers [in this github issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/410), if you're going to use the package with python 2 you must install version v19.0.0 or less.

So try uninstalling the package from the venv with `$ pip uninstall googleads` (assuming you have an newer version than v.19.0.1 and you're using python 2) ,then install the latest version that supports python 2 with `$ pip install googleads==19.0.1` in the venv.

Also ensure that you're running `python 2` with `$ python --version` to use the version 19.0.1.

If you want to use python 3 then install the latest version of the package. Also ensure that you updated the code since from the changelog "Also `suds` is no longer supported in this library, `zeep` is now the only supported SOAP client.
" [suds has been deprecated.](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/ChangeLog#L14)